# How to handle recapcha on webdriverio?

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I am having an issue when running multiple tests one after another in webdriverio. When I am running multiple tests (for example a describe that contains multiple it) I am getting a recapcha that basically fails the test. Is there a way to overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: Only way is to either stay under the CAPTCHA triggering activity threshold, or ask your DEV team to provide you with a bypass mechanism. CAPTCHA has a sole purpose, of deflecting automation, meaning you, so you cannot pass through a steel & concrete wall, so go over it somehow.

Comment: Usually there always is a Google `jwt` token that the DEV team can provide, which can be passed in as a URL param when you encounter the CAPTCHA link.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using node. You would either have to detect the captcha and give it to the user (you), or find a way to not spam the website enough that it decides you are a robot. Note however, that that is hardly possible as the website obviously doesn't want bots if it uses ReCaptcha. There is no way to just bypass ReCaptcha without humans (yet)

Answer (score 0):

I recently automated reCAPTCHA QA version (which just need click). Here is the code for same.

```
public async clickCheckbox(): Promise<void> {
const iframe = $('iframe[title="reCAPTCHA"]');

await iframe.click({ x: 30, y: 30 });
```

}